# Ternary operator in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I am trying to use the ternary operator in one of my mailers files..

```
body += "<p>UTM_SOURCE: #{user.get_utm_params[:source]}</p>" if user.get_utm_params[:source].present? + ":" + "<p>N/A</p>"
```

I am appending this data output to the body of a mail I am sending through my app, trying to use the ternary operator but I keep getting a NoMethodError for "+"

Comment: There is no ternary operator there, there's just a method ending in `?` and a `+`. The ternary operator looks like this: `a ? b : c`, not `if a? + ":" + "b"`. There should be no `if`. Can you explain what you're trying to do? Is your intent to output `user.get_utm_params[:source]` if it's present, and `N/A` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good case for the ternary operator. If your want to output `x` if `x` is present or `y` otherwise, use the `presence` method and the `||` operator. `presence` will return the value if it is `present?` or `nil` otherwise, it effectively "casts" the value to something truthy/falsy based on its `presence?` so that you can use it with boolean operators.

```
body += "<p>UTM_SOURCE: #{user.get_utm_params[:source].presence || "N/A"}</p>"
```

A better solution is to define a helper method that will return either the source or `"N/A"` for you, and take this logic out of your mailer.

---

As an aside, the right way to use a ternary operator here would be:

```
utm_source = user.get_utm_params[:source]
body += "<p>UTM_SOURCE: #{utm_source.present? ? utm_source : "N/A"}</p>"
```

Note that there is no `if` involved in a ternary operator, and that the `present?` method's question mark is *not* part of the operator. You still need all three operands and both operator characters, `a ? b : c` even if `a` ends in a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax in your code.

```
body += "<p>UTM_SOURCE: #{user.get_utm_params[:source]}</p>#{user.get_utm_params[:source].present? ? ':' : '<p>N/A</p>'}"
```

Or

```
body += "<p>UTM_SOURCE: #{user.get_utm_params[:source]}</p>"
body += user.get_utm_params[:source].present? ? ':' : '<p>N/A</p>'
```